# What is the difference between 'secure' and 'secured'?

Tags: word-usage, difference, adjectives

I have seen usages of both words, 'secure' and 'secured'. The fact that highlights that the two are different is that they have different antonyms:

- 'secure' has the antonym 'insecure'.
- 'secured' has the antonym 'unsecured'.

They're both adjectives, that much I know.

What is the exact difference between the two?

Comment: Check the definitions of [***secure***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/secure). These are derived from different definitions. To give a specific explanation, example phrases should be added.

Comment: Turn the adjective into a verb and all of your questions are answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example: "Your insecure bike is secured by a lock."

- So it can not be stolen because it is locked.
- But you shall not use it before fixing the brakes.

Secured and unsecured are states depending on a mostly simple action (using a lock, switching a safety catch).

Secure and insecure are an inherent characteristic. They may also be changed by actions (repairing the brakes) but with more effort and intervention.